# Is it more correct to say "transcript list" or "transcripts list?"

Tags: grammar

When referring to a list of X, such as a list of transcripts, is it more correct to say "transcript list" or "transcripts list"?

That is, when one referring to a list of something, should the name of the thing be pluralized or not?

Comment: Yes, it's more correct and we should do it, but we often don't and no-one minds. What matters most is to be understood. The first time it's mentioned, "list of transcripts" would be perfect. If it needs mentioning again, "the list" or "that list" might do. When *spoken*, the jangling sound of "transcripts list" is mildly distracting.

Comment: Duck soup! Noun adjuncts do not need to be pluralized. The singular is correct.

Comment: See previous related posts right here for more.  Good Luck.